# Gtmetrix shows 6.2 seconds but waiting time 20 seconds

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I have an ecommerce website in wordpress. its Gtmetrix score B(89%) and shows "fully loaded time" of 6.2 seconds but website loads almost in 20 seconds.  Screenshot is here https://prnt.sc/mu11kw and this is watarfall https://prnt.sc/mu13id
Over 95% of the time it takes to load the page is "Wait" time as shown in the this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/mu0zgd

on the other hand score of competitor company's website is D(60%) this is SS https://prnt.sc/mu1gsz but "wait time" almost none.

So I use wp fastest cache plugin and optimized all photos. I don't think the problem is with my server beacuse i don't experience such a problem on other html websites. i don't understand why this site waiting time is too long?

Comment: I just tested your site in Dev Tools and there are performance issues beyond the scope of the topics you have tagged your question with. From my perspective `pagespeed` and `gtmetrix` are for asking questions on how to interpret test results and on how to achieve the different suggestions given by the test tools. I'm down-voting your question as off-topic as I believe it's a pure wordpress and basic web performance q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I checked your site on GTMetrix https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.lavidagiyim.com/0ccgExUe and if you see the waterfall result
  the plugin "yith-woocommerce-wishlist" might be causing high waiting
  time for each images that it shows. Try testing your site without
  this plugin.
- You need to also let go of unnecessary plugins as with each added
  plugin creates a overhead which might leads to high load time.

Comment: thank you for answer.  i changed cache plugin and now use litespeed cache plugin. now the situation is a little better. my server company said me "litespeed works better with our server"  and "Gtmetrix etc. does not give real results" i dont know!